# tailwindcss typography "SassC::SyntaxError: Error: unterminated attribute selector for type"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, sprockets

I upgraded the `tailwindcss-rails` gem and got this error when compiling assets for production:

```
bundle exec rails assets:precompile
rails aborted!
SassC::SyntaxError: Error: unterminated attribute selector for type
        on line 1009:16 of stdin
>> .prose ol[type="A" s] {

   ---------------^
/home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/gems/sassc-ruby-4fce2b635ca5/lib/sassc/engine.rb:50:in `render'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc/rails/compressor.rb:29:in `call'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:30:in `call'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept having the `SassC::SyntaxError`. Adding the following line in `production.rb` resolved the issue:

```
config.assets.css_compressor = nil
```

It will prevent **sassc-rails** from setting sass as the compressor.

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70665740/12099013).

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that this new syntax for CSS rules is not supported by libsass / sassc.

So I ended up forking tailwindcss-rails and remove the extras.

It's on GitHub: https://github.com/dorianmariefr/tailwindcss-rails/tree/minimal

And you can use it like this in your `Gemfile`:

```rb
gem "tailwindcss-rails",
    github: "dorianmariefr/tailwindcss-rails",
    branch: "minimal"
```

Comment: I had a similar issue where I couldn't use `@tailwind/typography`, what I ended up doing was changing the file type of the file i was importing tailwind into from `.scss` to `.css`. Although that might not be suitable for your usecase.

Comment: Did you consider switching to [dart-sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) instead? `libsass` is no longer under development and will become less and less compatible as front end packages start using stuff like the new `@use` module system.

Comment: @max I would love to switch to dart-sass, just not sure how to do it

Comment: I missed that you were still using sprockets which might make the transition more challenging.

Comment: looks like in might be fixed in Rails 7 https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43110