# Rails 7 asset pipeline SassC::SyntaxError with Tailwind

Tags: ruby-on-rails, build, asset-pipeline, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm working on getting a new Rails 7 project deployed to production (trying on both Heroku and Render.com) and am getting the following error during build:

```
$ tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css

       Done in 408ms.
       Done in 0.90s.
       rake aborted!
       SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Function rgb is missing argument $green.
               on line 428 of stdin
       >>   color: rgb(29 78 216 / var(--tw-text-opacity));

          ---------^
       stdin:428
```

That's what I *think* is the relevant part, but here's a bit more context of the output if it's helpful.

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       yarn install v1.22.17
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 5.10s.
       yarn run v1.22.17
       $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds
       
         app/assets/builds/application.js      185.5kb
         app/assets/builds/application.js.map  301.0kb
       
       Done in 0.10s.
       yarn install v1.22.17
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       success Already up-to-date.
       Done in 0.12s.
       yarn run v1.22.17
       $ tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css
       
       Done in 408ms.
       Done in 0.90s.
       rake aborted!
       SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Function rgb is missing argument $green.
               on line 428 of stdin
       >>   color: rgb(29 78 216 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
       
          ---------^
       stdin:428
       /tmp/build_d9d0bde2/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/engine.rb:50:in `render'
       /tmp/build_d9d0bde2/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc/rails/compressor.rb:29:in `call'
       /tmp/build_d9d0bde2/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:30:in `call'
       /tmp/build_d9d0bde2/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
```

I set up the project using `rails new project_name -j esbuild --css tailwind`. Development mode works fine, just production deployment.

I'm not really sure where to even begin debugging this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Preventing sassc-rails from setting sass as the compressor fixed it for me.

Add this to application.rb

`config.assets.css_compressor = nil`

Comment: This has worked for me, thanks - would be lovely to get a bit more info on the answer as to why it works and any drawbacks @VincentBakker :)

Comment: This works because sassc-rails tries to compress tailwindCSS files, which is not desirable since TailwindCSS is designed to be used without compression. So sassc-rails tries to compress tailwind, and this causes a conflict, and errors. So by disabling css compression, it solves the conflict. However, this means that CSS assets(not tailwind) will not be compressed, resulting in larger CSS files, which could potentially effect performance. I believe the more elegant fix is the gems need to be re-worked to play nicely whether you're using tailwind, or sass/css. But that's easier said than done.

Answer (score 6):

From rails tailwind readme

> Tailwind uses modern CSS features that are not recognized by the sassc-rails extension that was included by default in the Gemfile for Rails 6. In order to avoid any errors like SassC::SyntaxError, you must remove that gem from your Gemfile.

https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails

Comment: If I do that, then I get a new error: `LoadError: cannot load such file -- sassc`

Comment: do you know that there is a gem for sassc?

Comment: You may have a dependency that depends on sassc. Check your Gemfile.lock

Comment: I was also getting `LoadError: cannot load such file -- sassc` as well even after setting `config.assets.css_compressor = nil`. The problem was I still had `scaffolds.scss` in my application so Sprockets would still load the `Sprockets::SassCompressor`

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Vincent's answer, I put `config.assets.css_compressor = nil` in `config/environments/production.rb`. Putting it in `application.rb` did not work.

I also still have the `sassc-rails` gem installed

Comment: That worked for me for `Unable to resolve 'tailwindcss/base' for missing asset 'tailwindcss/base' in application.tailwind.css`

Answer (score 1):

[Tomca32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70401324/7573223)'s answer explains why we are getting the error

However, I needed to do something since I still needed process Sass/Scss and could not just remove the `sassc-rails` gem, I needed to replace it.

I am running [cssbundling-rails](https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails) and esbuild in order to use Tailwind.

My solution came from running:

```
bundle remove sassc-rails
rails css:install:sass
```

then updating my `package.json` to include both the sass and tailwind commands.  I did this by prepending the added sass command and `&&` to the existing tailwind command:

```js
"scripts": {
    "build:css": "sass ... && tailwindcss ...",
    "build": "node ./esbuild.config.js"
  }
```

I also needed to clean up and extra `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>` in my `layout/application.html` that got added from the build command and then my error cleared up.

Comment: This feels the right answer to me - unfortunately, I've a dependency that includes `sassc-rails` so haven't cracked the problem this way yet, but wanted to say a big thanks and +1 on this :)

Comment: I did the same as you but did not manage to make it work with `--watch` parameter for development environment. Did you create 4 separate scripts (2 for dev and 2 for prod -saas and tailwind)?

Answer (score 0):

the selected answer was not the solution for me. using `dartsass-rails` with sprockets and having a `manifest.js` with these contents:

```
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../builds
```

creates conflicts with `application.*css` being in the builds directory and probably in your `stylesheets`

I had to move all sass files into their own dir to really get around this, and created a `app/assets/sass` dir, then had to do this:

```
# config/initializers/dartsass.rb 
Rails.application.config.dartsass.builds = {
  "../sass/application.scss"                 => "application.css",
  # other files in ../sass
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep SASS compression enabled, you can monkey patch `Sprockets::SassCompressor` to skip the Tailwind css - set the following in an initializer:

```rb
# Required to stop Sprockets attempting to compress Tailwind CSS

require "sprockets/sass_compressor"

module SkipSassCompressionForTailwind
  TAILWIND_SEARCH = "! tailwindcss".freeze

  def call(input)
    if skip_compression?(input[:data])
      input[:data]
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def skip_compression?(body)
    body.include?(TAILWIND_SEARCH)
  end
end

Sprockets::SassCompressor.prepend SkipSassCompressionForTailwind
```