# Elasticbeanstalk + Ruby 3.2.2 platform sassc LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ruby-3, sassc

I'm getting error when trying to deploy Rails 7.1 application on ElasticBeanstalk Ruby 3.2 platform

Could not open library
/var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/libsass.so': /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/libsass.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. (LoadError)

ruby version 3.2.2

- I checked the files on server, there is no libsass.so file in gems folder, while on local machine it's in place.
- locally is working
- The deployment finished with "status":"SUCCESS"
- On previous Ruby-3.0.6 platform everything was ok.

Never see that happened before. Frustrated.

Tried to run bundle install manually on server, the same.

UPDATE: Finally I spent some time to learn how to use Docker with Rails. Now deployment goes much faster also any binary dependency can be easily included to the build. Not using EB ruby platform anymore.

Comment: No, deployment should go automatically

Answer (score 2):

i was getting the same error. Downgrading sassc to 2.1 in gemfile solved problem for me:

```
gem 'sassc', '~> 2.1'
```

Please check [this](https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/issues/146) issue for more answers. Installing sassc with `--disable-march-tune-native` option seems to be a solution for most cases.

Comment: Yes, seems like the issue caused by long time taken by sassc-2.4 installation which finally breaks the deployment. I tried to switch back to version 2.1, but then I'm getting SassC::SyntaxError: Error: error in C function font-path: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (SassC::SyntaxError) and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: I got that error too, because of font-awesome-sass gem. Can you try to change it like this: `gem 'sassc', '~> 2.1', '< 2.2'`.  if this not work try to run assets:precompile. i don't exactly remember but one of these should fix that error.

Comment: I'm also using font-awesome-sassc. I pissed off and removed the EB ruby 3.2 instance because of that error. For me, I decided that there are 2 possible solutions here - a)replace font-awesome with let's say material-icons or b)wait till they replace sassc with dart sass (which I hope should not have such installation problems)

Comment: Hi. I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401077/rails-7-asset-pipeline-sasscsyntaxerror-with-tailwind/70665740#70665740) answer as a better workaround for SassC::SyntaxError. If you consider to upgrade again :)